# select n largest using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

This is likely a novice question about LINQ, but assuming I have a set of Items with a DateTime property, one date having at most one item, how would I go about selecting the N most recent items from a date of reference, that is, the N items which have a date smaller that the requested date, and the largest date?
My naive thought would be to first select items with a date smaller than the reference date, sort by date, and select the N first items from that subset.

```
 var recentItems = from item in dataContext.Items
              where item.Date<=date 
              orderby item.Date descending 
              select item;

 var mostRecentItems = recentItems.Take(5).ToList();
```

Is this the "right" way to do it, or are there obviously better ways to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct method.  Judging by the word `dataContext` in there, I'm assuming that this is Linq to SQL code; it will get turned into an efficient `TOP N` query.

(Well, "efficient" as long as the data is indexed by date.)

One thing I might change is to remove the `ToList()`.  Unless you actually need it to be a *list*, it is *typically* better to leave it alone as an `IEnumerable<T>`, especially if you just need to iterate over it as opposed to obtaining elements by index.

Edit: I should qualify what I mean by *better* in reference to `ToList`.  When you call `ToList`, you end up with an in-memory structure that contains *all* of the elements in the set.  This uses up memory that you don't always need to be using.  Creating the list also requires a full iteration of all records, so if you later iterate the list itself, you've gone through every element twice.

For only 5 elements, the difference probably will not be noticeable; however, for 5000 elements it may matter quite a lot.  Therefore, you should get in the habit of not using `ToList()` unless you are certain that you need it.  Most of the time, you don't.

Comment: The DataContext is coming from EF. And thanks for both useful comments on indexing on dates, and on using ToList(). In this specific case, I do need a list, even though the reason is not mentioned in the problem description!

Answer (score 3):

yeah that's exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is fine. You could also do this in 1 sentence:

```
 var recentItems = (from item in dataContext.Items
              where item.Date<=date 
              orderby item.Date descending 
              select item).Take(5).ToList();
```

but your way is equally good.